# Xdebug doesn't show the full array

Tags: arrays, xdebug, stdclass

I run into a weird problem with Xdebug. In short, Xdebug doesn't show me the full array. It looks like a heisenbug. It only happens in some cases. Please have a look below.

[image]

Xdebug shows me in some cases only 2 array items, but in reality there are 6.

Here is my php.ini

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 12
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 1024
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 4096
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Maybe it is a NetBeans issue?  Have you tried VS Code or PhpStorm?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel It could be a Netbeans issue. But I did not try PHPStorm yet. Is PHPStorm better then Netbeans?

Comment: IMO, PhpStorm is >1000% better than NetBeans. I've been using is since before 1.0, and I cannot imaging working without it.

Comment: Any Update on this having a simmilar issue in vscode